# how to update checkbox in webgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

excuse me, i try to make webgrid, in webgrid i put checkbox. i want to change value of checkbox. i have 5 row in webgrid, in first row, value of checkbox success to change. but in row two until five, the value can change. can some one tell me, what my mistake?

this my view

```
<div id="mygrid">
</div>
<div>
    @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(Model.DataDiriList, rowsPerPage: 15, canPage: true, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
        @grid.GetHtml(
                           tableStyle: "row",
                  alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                  columns: grid.Columns(
                  grid.Column("ID", format: @<text>  <span  class="display-mode">@item.ID </span> <label id="UserID" class="edit-mode">@item.ID</label> </text>, style: "col1Width" ),
                  grid.Column("Nama", "Nama", format: @<text>  <span  class="display-mode"> <label id="lblNama"  >@item.Nama</label> </span> <input type="text" id="Nama" value="@item.Nama" class="edit-mode" /></text>, style: "col2Width"),
                  grid.Column("Umur", "Umur", format: @<text>  <span  class="display-mode"> <label id="lblUmur"  >@item.Umur</label> </span> <input type="text" id="Umur" value="@item.Umur" class="edit-mode" /></text>, style: "col2Width"),
                  grid.Column(header: "Active", format:@<text> <span  class="display-mode"> <label id="lblActive">@item.ActiveStatus</label> </span> <input id="chkActive" type="checkbox" @((item.Active == true) ? " checked=checked" : "") name="CloseSelling" value="@item.Active" class="edit-mode" onchange="adchange()" /></text>, style: "col2Width"),
                  grid.Column("Action", format: @<text>
                                <button class="edit-user display-mode" >Edit</button>
                                <button class="save-user edit-mode"  >Save</button>
                                <button class="cancel-user edit-mode" >Cancel</button>
                            </text>,  style: "col3Width" , canSort: false)
                 ));
    }
</div>

@section scripts
    {
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.edit-mode').hide();
            $('.edit-user, .cancel-user').on('click', function () {
                var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
                tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();
            });
            $(function () {
                $('#chkActive').click(function () {
                    alert($(this).val() + ' ' + (this.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'));
                });
            });

            $(".save-user").on("click", function () {
                var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
                var t = tr.find("#Nama").val();
                var Umur = tr.find('#Umur').val();
                var chkActive = $('#chk').attr('checked') ? "True" : "False";
                var ID = tr.find('#UserID').html();
                alert(chkActive);

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateUser", "Home")',
                type: "Post",
                data: { CustomerNameId: t, UserID: ID, Umur: Umur,Active: chkActive},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#mygrid").html('');
                    $("#mygrid").html(result);
                }
                });

                tr.find("#lblNama").text(t);
                tr.find("#lblUmur").text(Umur);
                tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();
        });

    });
</script>
    }
```

this Controller

```
public JsonResult UpdateUser(string CustomerNameId, string UserID, string Umur, bool Active)
        {
            var ID = Convert.ToInt32(UserID);
            var IntUmur = Convert.ToInt32(Umur);
            var dd = db.DataDiris.AsQueryable().Where(r => r.ID == ID).Single();
            dd.ID = ID;
            dd.Nama = CustomerNameId;
            dd.Umur = IntUmur;
            dd.Active = Active;

            db.Entry(dd).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            string message = "Success";
            return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

please help me

thanks

Answer (score 0):

for the issue of checkbox and the mvc webgrid,
you just need to add a short script.

this is the solution:
in the grab script things are all the same:

```
var IsDisabled = tr.find("#IsDisabled").val();
```

&

```
tr.find("#lblIsDisabled").text(IsDisabled);
```

&

```
"IsDisabled": IsDisabled,
```

so far its all the same, but you need to add the checkbox, like so:

```
grid.Column("IsDisabled", "IsDisabled", format: @<text> <span  class="display-mode"> <label id="lblIsDisabled">@item.IsDisabled</label> </span>  
<input class="edit-mode" id="IsDisabled" name="IsDisabled" type="checkbox" value="@if (item.IsDisabled){<text>True</text>}else{<text>False</text>}" @if(item.IsDisabled){<text>checked</text>}/>
</text>),
```

instead(!) you can also use the mvc html helper like so:

```
@Html.CheckBox("ShowOnChart", (bool)item.ShowOnChart, new { @class = "edit-mode", value = item.ShowOnChart })
```

eventually all you need is to add this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').change(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $(this).attr("value", true);
        } else {
            $(this).attr("value", false);
        }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $(this).attr("value", true);
        } else {
            $(this).attr("value", false);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

if you have more checkboxes in the page and you want to exclude them just use:

```
$('.edit-mode:checkbox').change(...
```

when receiving the bool in the controller i like going:

```
bool? isDisabled
```

just to be more representable if the ActionResult is not always called with the isDisabled input.

hope this helps.